# how to get a cycle without using a loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im teaching my self python and i came across this interesting question which says:

Implement a generator cycle such that if we assign
 i = cycle()
then repeated calls to
 next(i)
return the values
 me 
myself
i
me
myself
i
 ...

I can't use a for loop but only a generator or stream. I cant use libraries. I need to output it 20 times

what I've tried so far but i cant manage to get the cycle to work:

```
def cycle(i):   
    saved = []
    for el in m:
        yield el

        saved.append(el)
    while saved:
        for el in saved:
              yield element
```

Comment: `for el in m`: where did `m` come from? change it into `i` and it should work fine :P

Comment: As Chris suggested, `m` should be `i` as that is the list you are iterating through. Another question, why append the list to another list before iterating through it?

Comment: Is it allowed to use for loop to get iterator values?

Comment: @PavelAntspovich no

Comment: It's not clear how function will return multiple values simultaneously

Comment: @PavelAntspovich I need to implement it using something called stream,(infinite list)

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts (including your own). You can utilize the self-delete option while available. Keep in mind that, upon posting your question, the contents were licensed under CC by-SA 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want:

```
def cycle(n=0):
    saved=['me','myself','i']
    while True:
        yield saved[n]
        n = (n+1) % 3

i = cycle()
for _ in range(20):
   print(next(i))
```

Comment: Yes of course. The for loop is only for demonstration - the generator is the cycle() function.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer so that the generator generates EXACTLY 20 items before the iteration stops. You can call next(i) to get the next item. In the example I have collected the generator output into a list - just for demonstration.

Comment: but i can only use but only a generator or stream.

Comment: cycle() is a generator which returns a stream - i.e. an infinite list of items - yielding the next item every time you call next().

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `loop`s at all, try this:

```
class cycle:
    def __init__(self,lst,maxstep = 20):
        self.lst = lst
        self.n = 0
        self.len = len(lst)
        self.maxstep = maxstep
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n>=self.maxstep:      # remove this line
            raise StopIteration       # and this line, if you want infinite stream
        ret = self.lst[self.n % self.len]
        self.n += 1
        return ret
obj = cycle(['me','myself','i'])
```

If you want to be able to call `list` on it, that is make it `iterable`:

```
class cycle():
    def __init__(self,lst,maxstep = 20):
        self.lst = lst
        self.n = 0
        self.i = 0
        self.len = len(lst)
        self.maxstep = maxstep
    def __iter__(self):
        while self.i < self.maxstep:
            yield self.lst[self.i % self.len]
            self.i += 1
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n>=self.maxstep:
            raise StopIteration
        ret = self.lst[self.n % self.len]
        self.n += 1
        return ret
obj = cycle([1, 2, 3])
print(list(obj))
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
# or
# print(next(obj))
# 1
```

Comment: This is a generator implementation that will generate stream of cycles if you call `next` on it, until it reaches `maxstep`. If you want it to be `iterable` you can use my second method, then you can call `list` on it, and you will get the list cycled 20 times.

Comment: No, if you do that you will need some kind of loop, either `while` or `for`. In that case the first answer will suit you best.